# Define Group based on data in a column oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a table with a oracle sequence in col 1 and I need to make groups based on values in col 2.
Below is sample table with data. DB version = Oracle 12.1

> The condition for grouping is either col2 should have 50  or if it has
>   30 then next 50 should fall in the same group. There cannot be 30 alone.It will be followed by 50

I wrote the below,but not getting the expected outcome

```
SELECT col1,col2,count(CASE WHEN col2 in (30,50) THEN 1 END)OVER(ORDER BY col1) from table.
```

At the end I need the highest group, that will be doable.

```
Col1  Col2   Expected output Grp
----- -----  -------------------
1      3
2      50        1
3      10
4      2
5      30        2
6      12
7      50        2
8      14
9      50        3
10     50        4
```

Comment: can you fill in the missing group numbers as well?

Comment: @vamsi-prabhala yes you can,I just need 1 row where the group is max.in case of (30,50 ) pair,if that's the last group,I need the row with 30

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I think the logic goes like this:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when col2 = 50 and
                     (prev_30 is null or prev_30 < prev_50)
                then 1 else 0
           end) over (order by col1) as grp
from (select t.*,
             lag(case when col2 = 50 then col1 end ignore nulls) over (order by col1) as prev_50,
             lag(case when col2 = 30 then col1 end ignore nulls) over (order by col1) as prev_30
      from t
     ) t;
```

The idea is to get the previous `col1` value for "50" and for "30", which we can do with the `ignore null`s option on `lag()` (or using a cumulative conditional max).

Then the logic for defining the group is a cumulative sum of the "50"s that start each group.

Comment: Hi Gordon,thanks a lot for the explanation and super quick reply.I have one more requirement, and i think that will change the query formation

Comment: sorry I didn't try the query yet,as I am in transit,but I got it what your wrote. If I say I just need 1 row the last group ( and if it's the 30-50 group then the row which has 30 in it),we can have an outer query on the one u wrote ,but can we shorten it.